# jQuery toolbar hover flickering

Tags: jquery, css

Please have a look at my example - http://jsfiddle.net/5aKt8/3/

I want to show the appropriate toolbar when user hover each box.. it works fine, except when the user hover over the toolbar itself, it then starts flickering. I think hovering over the toolbar triggers a mouseout event on the hosting div, which starts a show/hide loop. not sure how to avoid this behaviour.. any ideas?

**CSS**

```
.box{
      display:block;
      border: 1px solid green;
      max-height: 50px;
      margin: 5px;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000000;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 80%;
      position: relative;
      color: #000;
      padding:10px;
}
.toolbar{
      font-size: 70%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right:0px;
      padding: 3px;
      color: blue;
      display:none;
      background: #aaa;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:10px">
<ul>
    <li class="box">
        <div class="toolbar">toolbar</div>
        some conetent
    </li>
    <li class="box">
        <div class="toolbar">toolbar</div>
        some conetent
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').mouseover(function(e){
        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').show();
    }).mouseout(function(e){
        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` instead, that stops the flickering.

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').mouseenter(function(e){
        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').css({display:'block'});
    }).mouseleave(function(e){
        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').css({display:'none'});
    });
});
```

[**jQuery jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5aKt8/6/)

---

Although, you don't actually need jQuery to do this - it can be done in pure CSS:

```
.box:hover .toolbar {
    display:block;
}
```

[**Pure CSS jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5aKt8/7/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/5aKt8/5/

use `mouseenter` and  `mouseleave`

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').mouseenter(function(e){
        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').css({display:'block'});
    }).mouseleave(function(e){
        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').css({display:'none'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript at all. Just add this CSS:

```
.box:hover > .toolbar{
     display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .hover() function instead of mouseover, this script should work instead of the one in your fiddle:

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').hover(function(e){
        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').css({display:'block'});
    }, function(e){

        $(e.target).find('.toolbar').css({display:'none'});

    });
});
```

The browser will fire the mouseout when you hover over the tooltip, therefor it will flicker.

Best regards.
Jonas